# Extracting string and integer into a dictionary

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to understand how I can extract a particular type of string into a dictionary with its values.

Ex:

> item SHIRT 11-14 variance 11-12-13-14-15 color Red

where

```
ShirtType: 11, 14
variance: 11,12,13,14,15
color: Red
```

Would love the idea of using regexp and see how that can be achieved in Python? All ideas are welcome.

Comment: Only use python2/python3 tags for **version specifc questions**.

Comment: is the text always static for the `item SHIRT`, `variance`, `color` part ?

Comment: Added [one-liner solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045525/2063361) to get your desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your input is always like that you can use `regex` to extract the values and insert them into a dictionary:

```
import re

dic = {}
input = 'item SHIRT 11-14 variance 11-12-13-14-15 color Red'
dic['Shirt Type'] = re.search('(?<=SHIRT\s)[\d-]+', input).group().split('-')
dic['Variance'] = re.search('(?<=variance\s)[\d-]+', input).group().split('-')
dic['Color']= re.search('(?<=color\s)\w+', input).group().split('-')
print(dic)
```

the result will be a dictionary with 3 `keys` and each `value` will be an array (size of array depends on the input and the number of the <kbd>-</kbd> in it) for example this is the result of your input:

```
{'Shirt Type': ['11', '14'], 'Variance': ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15'], 'Color': ['Red']}
```

Comment: I tried dic['Color']= re.search('(?<=color\s)\w+', input).group().split('-'), but getting an error as TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. Can it not be an array type for color? since it will always have one color

Comment: remove the `split('-')` so it returns a string

Comment: great, got it working, actually I was using input and should have replaced with the declared string itself.

Answer (score 1):

You may use below [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) expressions to extract the required values from the string. Here's the one-liner to get the desired `dict`:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_str = "item SHIRT 11-14 variance 11-12-13-14-15 color Red"
>>> keys = ["shirt", "variance", "color"]

>>> {k: v.split('-') if '-' in v else v for k, v in zip(keys, re.findall(
        '(?<=SHIRT\s)[\d-]+|(?<=variance\s)[\d-]+|(?<=color\s)\w+',my_str))}
```

which will return the `dict` object as:

```
{'color': 'Red', 'variance': ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15'], 'shirt': ['11', '14']}
```

**Explanation** of each regex pattern:

```
# For shirt: 
#     This regex matches the number and hyphen "-" 
#     preceded by "variance" and space " "
>>> re.search('(?<=SHIRT\s)[\d-]+', my_str).group()
'11-14'       

# For variance:
#     Same as the above regex, it matches the number and hyphen "-" 
#     preceded by "SHIRT" and space " "
>>> re.search('(?<=variance\s)[\d-]+', my_str).group()
'11-12-13-14-15'

# For color:
#     This regex matches the alphabets followed by "color" and space " "
>>> re.search('(?<=color\s)\w+', my_str).group()
'Red'
```

Using this you can assign each key individually to your `dict` explicitly too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "item SHIRT 11-14 variance 11-12-13-14-15 color Red"
new_s = s.split()[1:]
final_data = {"ShirtType" if a == "SHIRT" else a:map(int, b.split('-')) if re.findall('\d\-', b) else b for a, b in [(new_s[i], new_s[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(new_s)-1, 2)]}
```

Output:

```
{'color': 'Red', 'ShirtType': [11, 14], 'variance': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try without using regex:

One line solution:

```
print({line.split()[1:][i:i+2][0]:line.split()[1:][i:i+2][1] for line in open('file.txt','r') for i in range(0,len(line.split()[1:]),2)})
```

output:

```
{'color': 'Red', 'variance': '11-12-13-14-15', 'SHIRT': '11-14'}
```

Detailed version:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        chunk=line.split()[1:]
        print({chunk[i:i+2][0]:chunk[i:i+2][1] for i in range(0,len(chunk),2)})
```